# Como pegar a requisição do cliente?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Estou a tentar pegar a sessão do usuário a partir da requisição, porém não tenho certeza se estou capturando a requisição de maneira correta:
Tenho um *Managed Bean* (*SessionScoped*) com dados. O seguinte bloco cria a sessão de um usuário em uma situação de login:

```java
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Usuario {
    private String login;
    private String senha;
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    ...
    //getters, setters.
    ...
    public Boolean logon() {
        //validações que checam se o usuário existe e colocou a senha correspondente.
    }
}
```

```xhtml
<p:inputText value="#{Usuario.login}"/>
<p:inputText value="#{Usuario.senha}"/>
<p:commandButton value="entrar" action="#{Usuario.logon}"/>
```

O usuário pode ter clientes e se desejar ver quem são, desenrolei o seguinte:

```java
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Cliente {
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private String endereco;
    ...
    //getters, setters.
    ...
    public ArrayList<Cliente> clientes(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            return new ClienteDAO().selectClientes(request);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            //
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

```java
public class ClienteDAO {
    public ArrayList<Cliente> selectClientes(HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException {
        ArrayList<Cliente> dataGrid;
        try {
            Usuario usuario = (Usuario)((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession().getAttribute("Usuario");
            //PreparedStatement ps...
            //O comando tem um parâmetro que busca de acordo com o login do usuário.
            ps.setString(1, usuario.getLogin);
            //Executa o comando e atribui os dados do ResultSet ao ArrayList dataGrid;
        }
        return dataGrid;
    }
}
```

```xhtml
<h:form>
    <p:dataGrid value="#{Cliente.clientes}" var="cliente">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{cliente.getNome}"/>
        <p:outputLabel value="#{cliente.getEmail}"/>
    </p:dataGrid>
</h:form>
```

O meu método funciona? Independente da resposta, existem outras maneiras de fazer o que quero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, deveria funcionar. Inclusive, você pode utilizar um método mais sofisticado para trabalhar com objetos em sessão no JSF, que é a utilização do [ExternalContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html).

```
ExternalContext contextoExterno = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
Map<String, Object> mapaSessao = contextoExterno.getSessionMap();
Usuario usuario = (Usuario) mapaSessao.get("usuario");
```

Outra sugestão seria você não misturar classes específicas da API dentro do seu modelo, no seu exemplo, o `HttpServletRequest` é um parâmetro do seu objeto de modelo `Cliente`. O que você poderia fazer é passar o Usuário ou o seu ID montado já no parâmetro. Também removeria o acoplamento do DAO de dentro do objeto de modelo e, para fechar, faria a inversão do comportamento, fazendo o objeto `Usuario` ter um método que retorne os seus clientes e não o `Cliente` retornando os clientes de um usuário. Mas aí já é uma questão mais arquitetural e foge do foco da pergunta.

Comment: Meu método depende da anotação `@RequestScoped`?

Comment: Isso apenas define o escopo da sua classe. No caso, a classe Cliente sendo RequestScoped será recriada a cada nova requisição *não mantendo o seu estado*. Diferente da SessionScoped, que continuará viva enquanto a sessão do usuário estiver ativa.

Comment: Eu preciso explicitar na chamada do método o atributo (`Cliente.clientes(request)`)? Pois quando deixo sem nenhum parâmetro, o NetBeans acusa que o método "clientes" é desconhecido.

Comment: posso usar o ExternalContext dentro de um método @PostConstruct?

Comment: Oi @Patrick, para ajudar a organizar as questões no site, por favor, crie um novo tópico por pergunta. Apesar de ser relacionada, sua pergunta não é mais a mesma do tópico que, já foi, inclusive, resolvida. Um abraço.